# Regex pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string :
`154545K->12345K(524288K)`

Suppose I want to extract numbers from this string.

The string contains the group `154545` at position `0`, `12345` at position `1` and `524288` at position `2`.

Using regex `\\d+`, I need to extract `12345` which is at position `1`.

I am getting the desired result using this :

```
String lString = "154545K->12345K(524288K)";
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher lMatcher = lPattern.matcher(lString);
String lOutput = "";
int lPosition = 1;
int lGroupCount = 0;
while(lMatcher.find()) {
    if(lGroupCount == lPosition) {
    lOutput = lMatcher.group();
    break;
}
else {
    lGroupCount++;
}
}
System.out.println(lOutput);
```

But, is there any other simple and direct way to achieve this **keeping the regex same `\\d+`**(without using the group counter)?

Comment: why dont you use matching groups and get result with backreferences ?

Comment: There is if you use capturing groups, however capturing groups start at 1, not 0

Comment: Yes, if I use capturing groups, the regex will be "(\\d+)K->(\\d+)K((\\d+)K)" and I get "154545" at '1', "12345" at '2' and "524288" at '3'. **But I need to keep the regex same, i.e "\\d+" only**. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String d1 = "154545K->12345K(524288K)".replaceAll("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect your number to be at the position 1, then you can use `find(int start)` method like this

```
if (lMatcher.find(1) && lMatcher.start() == 1) {
    // Found lMatcher.group()
}
```

You can also convert your loop into for loop to get ride of some boilerplate code

```
String lString = "154540K->12341K(524288K)";
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher lMatcher = lPattern.matcher(lString);


int lPosition = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < lPosition && lMatcher.find(); i++) {}

if (!lMatcher.hitEnd()) {
    System.out.println(lMatcher.group());
}
```